# white noise not forecastable ? stationarity doesn't imply forecastability?

Tags: stationarity, forecasting

We know that white noise isn't forecastable because of its random aspect. White noise is also stationary, and which is confusing me, is that we always try to make a serie stationary to make forecasts, hence I don't understant why white noise stationarity doesn't make it forecastable...

The only conclusion I see is that stationarity, doesn't imply forecastability. Thus, why are we always trying to make series stationaire, if it doesn't imply forecastability ?

Could someone please help me understand these notions ?

Thank you very much Habib

Comment: Actually, you can forecast white noise with very good accuracy: the expected value is always zero.

Comment: @LisaAnn, you can forecast white noise easily without *bias* (as you'd said), it's accuracy is obviously awful.

Comment: Hi: stationarity is a necessary ( but not sufficient ) condition for forecast-ability.  So, you need it but, even with it, forecasting can be difficult. If you don't have it, then you're really doomed.